# Kotlin Delegation

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

I am failing to understand how Kotlin Delegation works when it comes to enabling bluetooth on android.

I've come across this reference documentation on the Kotlin website but something seems to be going over my head.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html

```
interface Base {
    fun print()
}

class BaseImpl(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun print() { print(x) }
}

class Derived(b: Base) : Base by b

fun main() {
    val b = BaseImpl(10)
    Derived(b).print()
}
```

> The `by`-clause in the supertype list for `Derived` indicates that `b` will be stored internally in objects of `Derived` and the compiler will generate all the methods of `Base` that forward to `b`.

Basically, I understand the `BaseImpl` class inherits from `Base` and so when we declare `val b = BaseImpl(10)` everything works as if it were Java but once we introduce this `Derived` class I get confused as to what directive `: Base by b` is trying to achieve.

Are we only looking to implement the methods we want and overriding all the others?

I think I am getting lost in the abstracts of it all. So when I am looking to enable Bluetooth I'm not really sure what is going on here.

```
private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? by 
                                 lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
    val bluetoothManager = 
        getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    bluetoothManager.adapter
}
```

I hope I'm not asking too many questions or even too broad of a question but when we are declaring `bluetoothAdapter` when does it get initialized? Does is it get initialized right there or just when we use it? And does it get initialized with what's in between the `{}`s? Thus `bluetoothManager` is only within scope on `bluetoothAdapter`s initialization?

Please, forgive my ignorance.. It's a real struggle. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code snippet what basically happens is when the variable is called/used, the block of code in lazy{} gets executed and whatever result is in the last code gets stored in the variable.

So when the bluetoothAdapter is gonna be used like bluetoothAdapter.something(),
the very first time the bluetoothAdapter will be called, the lazy block will be executed and the result

```
 val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
 ---> bluetoothManager.adapter
```

Will be stored in the bluetoothAdapter variable and the block will be executed only once when it is first called.

It in simple terms is like calling

```
fun initializeAdapter():BluetoothManager? {
       val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
       return bluetoothManager.adapter
}
```

before using the bluetoothAdapter variable.

Comment: ahh.. I think that's making sense. I'm like a super newb to Kotlin and am trying to learn. What would that code or process of putting the code withing the lazy{} be called? Is that Delegation or related to the delegation pattern or is that just a different way to initialize? That seems to be somewhat common in Kotlin. Thanks again!

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html under Lazy

Comment: Glad to help :) Kotlin is an amazing language, you are gonna have a lot of fun using it!